# React redux prev state ignores and rewrites by next state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Below an example what's goes wrong in my app that I can't figure out how to fix it and why it's actually happening. 
I made a simple API call to fetch some data

```
    dispatch(isLoadingData(true));
        api({
              method,
              url,
              headers: { Authorization: `JWT ${APP.token}` }
            })
              .then(async (response) => {
                return resolve(dispatch(await updateData(response)));
              }).catch(reject);
          }).catch(async (err) => { 
              dispatch(isError(err));
              dispatch(await isLoadingData(false)); 
              throw err; 
          });
```

if API response has 401 status code that it initiates logout process by calling the next action.

```
 case LOGOUT_USER: {
          Actions.main({ type: 'reset' });
          return {
            ...INITIAL_STATE,
          };
        }
```

that restores the user reducer to

```
{ user: '', token: '' };
```

(It calls before Promise returns a response in the upper function). So the sequence looks like this

1) isLoadingData(true)

**2) logoutUser()** (this clears user data)

3) isError(err) (this again has user and token)

4) isLoadingData(false)

As a result, the user can't be logging out.

Comment: This is happening because these are async actions. To handle such actions you need to use a middleware. The most common is `redux-thunk`. Visit: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: @ArslanTariq thanks, 
but I use thunk in the app

Answer (score 0):

just add another

```
.then(response => dispatchActionAfterActualLogoutWasMade())
```

so that you dispatch the action after the initial logout request was completed

that will send an action to reducer to clear the app state after you already received the response from the server.